# Convert Dictionary into Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to convert a dictionary into a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
dict = {'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [1,2,3,4])
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient = 'index').T
```

Expect:

```
    A        B
0   [1,2,3]  [1,2,3,4]
```

But got instead:

```
   A      B
-----------
0  1      a
1  2      b
2  3      c
3  None   d
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put the dictionary inside list (`[]`):

```py
import pandas as pd

dct = {"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [1, 2, 3, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame([dct])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
           A             B
0  [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

Note: Don't use reserved words such as `dict` for variable names.